# Create Stripe Connect Customer with Payment Method on Platform Account

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following the docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide) about enabling other business to accept payments directly.

I have successfully created a connected account and accepted a payment from a customer on the connected account, but I have not yet been able to save that customers payment information for future payments.

All across the documentation, especially [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) it assumes you already created a customer on the platform account WITH a payment method, before you should try and clone the payment method to the connected accounts.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to create a customer with payment information on the platform account before I clone them on the connected account.

As per the documentation, I started here on the client side where the accountID is the ID of the connected account:

```
const [stripePromise, setstripePromise] = useState(() =>
    loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY, {
      stripeAccount: uid.accountID,
    })
  );
```

My Stripe Elements are created with the stripePromise.

When trying to save the card details I do this on the client side:

**This is where I believe my mistake is** I am using the connected accounts credentials while trying to create a platform payment method.

```
  const handleRememberMe = async () => {
    const { token } = await stripe.createToken(
      elements.getElement(CardElement)
    );
    console.log(token);

    const res = await fetchPostJSON("/api/pay_performer", {
      accountID: accountID,
      amount: value,
      cardToken: token,
    });
```

That API call goes to "/api/pay_performer":

```
//Handle onboarding a new connect user for x

require("dotenv").config();
import Stripe from "stripe";
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
});
import setCookie from "../../../utils/cookies";

export default async function createPayment(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
// Connected account ID and the token generated on the client to be saved.
    const { accountID, amount, cardToken } = req.body;
    console.log(`API side cardToken: ${cardToken.used}`);
    try {
      // Trying to create a customer with that token.
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: "test2@example.com",
        source: cardToken.card,
      });
      customer.sources = cardToken.card;
// Beginning the cloning process for the connected account.
      const token = await stripe.tokens.create(
        {
          customer: customer.id,
        },
        {
          stripeAccount: accountID,
        }
      );
      const clonedCustomer = await stripe.customers.create(
        {
          source: token.id,
        },
        {
          stripeAccount: accountID,
        }
      );
      console.log(`Default Source: ${clonedCustomer.default_source}`);

      console.log(`AccountID: ${accountID}, Amount: ${amount}`);
      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
        {
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          payment_method: clonedCustomer.default_source
            ? clonedCustomer.default_source
            : null,
          amount: amount * 100,
          currency: "usd",
          application_fee_amount: 1,
          customer: clonedCustomer.id,
        },
        {
          stripeAccount: accountID,
        }
      );

      const secret = paymentIntent.client_secret;
      console.log(secret);
      const payment_method = paymentIntent.payment_method;
      return res.status(200).send({ secret, payment_method });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return res.status(500).send({ error: e.message });
    }
  }
}
```

But I get an error that the token provided is not a valid token. I am assuming this is because I created the token using the credentials for the connected account on the client and then tried to apply it to the platform account.

How do I have a separate UI to create platform customers FIRST, and then come back and clone them to the connected accounts upon purchase.

Should I not pass a token to the server and just pass the card information over HTTPS? Very lost and the documentation has not helped!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a Customer, collect card information and attach a PaymentMethod to them, you could for example use a SetupIntent and Elements [1] or create a PaymentMethod [2]. The core point being, if the system should initially store that information on the platform, the connected account isn't coming into play at all yet. Broadly speaking the steps are (**not** providing the account id of the connected account anywhere as this is only happening on the platform account), using the platform's secret key:

1. Create a customer
2. Collect card data using Stripe.js and Elements
3. Attach the pm_xxx to the customer in the backend

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you!